# Javascript DOM confusion with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have this chunk Javascript of code in a Grails template:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var currentIndex = 0;
    var allIssues = $('#all-issues'); // The unordered list 'ul'
    var removeIssues = []; // An array to keep track of issues removed
    if (allIssues.length) { // If there are issues to be displayed
      var size = $('#all-issues').size();

      allIssues.first().removeClass("display-none");  
      allIssues.first().addClass("display");

      $('#startIndex').html(currentIndex + 1);      
      $('#sizeIndex').html(size);

      $('#nextRedIssue').on ('click' ,function () {           
           var $li = $('#all-issue.display');   
           var index = $('#all-issue').index($li)
           if (index < size) {           
              $li.addClass("display-none");
              $li.removeClass("display");

              var $nextLi = $('#all-issue').get(index++) 

              $nextLi.removeClass("display-none");
              $nextLi.addClass("display");
           }        
      });
  }
});
</script>
```

Now on second and third line where I define `var currentIndex` and `var allIssues`, they keep coming up as undefined (don't even exist) but that problem goes away when I move them outside of the DOM ready clause (but still within the  tags of course). I do not understand why this is and would like to know. It also seems like if I just remove the `document.ready wrapper`, all the variable that were undefined before start being define and work fine. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you repeating the same code on line 3-4?

Comment: @Mahdi Dibaiee, sorry I was playing around with placing that code in different places. I edited to remove confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the variables are defined *within* the **ready** function but not elsewhere in your program.

**If so:**
Note that JavaScript variables have function scope, which simply means they are defined only within the function itself.

[edit]
Variables declared outside any function have *global* scope, making them defined throughout your code (except where variables of the same name are declared within functions).  That's why you *can* see them if they're placed *outside* the **ready** function.  Note that you should avoid global variables, but we wouldn't know what to recommend without seeing the rest of your code. [end edit]

**If not:**
We may need to see more of your code.  `currentIndex` should be defined throughout the function, and `allIssues` should be defined as long as your **ul**'s id is `all-issues`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is your document is not actually "ready" when you are testing for the variables.  Perhaps you have some page pieces that have not fully completed their loading.  When are you testing for the existence of the variables?  Perhaps that test needs to be after the document is ready also.